# Is there a function to gather the amount of memory used in a specific File Directory

Tags: javascript

If you can include Javascript so it automatically updates that would be awesome. I want it to gather the amount of space that is being used in directory /wy/ and display on the index.php file and automatically update whenever a file is added to file directory /wy/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant achive this only with javascript as your tag implies. you may need to use any file APIs available. Better ways is to have a Server implementation for this and get the memory details from server using Ajax or any client-server communication techniques.

Comment: you welcome. your application have server implementations?

Comment: I am very knew to this, could you simplify what you mean?

Comment: is your application have a business logics runs somewhere like tomcat or jboss , or is this only a simple client side application ?

Comment: it's actually a website that's very much client sided except for some php.

Comment: Oh k. Anyways, you cant achieve what you wanted only by using javascript/client side scripts. post comments if u need any help further. Vote up if it helps.